# Coupon code does not exist in DevDemon Subscription

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-subscriptions

I added a coupon to the DevDemon subscription Coupon dashboard in the Control Panel.

I tried the coupon code within the subscribe tag.

```
{exp:subs:subscribe 
    payment_method="authorizenet_cim"
    plan="pro" 
    return="/join/create/%SUBS_HASH%"
}

<input name="coupon" type="text" value="{subs:coupon}">
```

It returns this error message:

> The submitted coupon code does not exist or is malformated.

The code does exist, I must be missing a small detail.

[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was posted a while back, but I faced the same issue, so posting the answer here in case it is of help:

You need to check if the coupons were created in Live or Test Mode. When working on a local server, only Test Mode coupons and vouchers are applied.